# How Can I Use the "in" with enum class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I have a enum class. That is:

```
enum{
us,
uk,
in,
}
```

that enum  class keeps the my country codes like at the above. But in the vscode showing that message:

```
'in' can't be used as an identifier because it's a keyword.
Try renaming this to be an identifier that isn't a keyword.
```

I wanna use the in like other ones. I gonna use that enum class for Api request. How can I use "in" with that class?

Answer (score 5):

Additional to harlekintiger :

Flutter 3 supports writing the enum like this too:

```dart
enum Country {
  usa('us'),
  unitedKingdoms('uk'),
  india('in');
  
  const Country(this.cc);
  
  final String cc;
}

final String cc = Country.uk.cc;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `in` in your enum because `in` is a reserved keyword for dart.

For example in dart you can write:

```
for (var item in items)
```

That's the reason why you can not call an identifier `in`

See [Keywords](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#keywords) for details.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to use the whole country name in your enum

```
enum Country{
  none,
  usa,
  unitedKingdoms,
  india,
}
```

instead of the codes. That also makes it easier while programming for those not knowing all the codes.
For passing it into the API, presumably as a string, you could use an extention method (pre Dart 2.17 aproach, for details see below)

```
extension CountryFunctionalities on Country{
  String get asCountryCode {
    switch (this) {
      case Country.usa: return "us";
      case Country.unitedKingdoms: return "uk";
      case Country.india: return "in";
      default: return "";
    }
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
Country countryInstance = Country.india;
print(countryInstance.asCountryCode); // output: "in"
```

---

If you use Dart 2.17 or newer, you can use the enhanced enum (thanks to @venir for the suggested edit). You can see it applied in [@Hannes answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73321477/5913518) or read more about it in [Michael Thomsen's blog post "Dart 2.17: Productivity and integration"](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-17-b216bfc80c5d)  under the header "Enhanced enums with members"

---

Alternatively you could use the Alpha-3 Code "IND" instad of the Alpha-2 Code "IN". https://www.iban.com/country-codes

---

Lastly you could simply use "IN" instead of "in" as a name, that is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: This of course gets simpler with the 2.17-added enhanced enums.